# SQL oracle How delete empty rows to use get method

Tags: sql, oracle

Could You please tell modify below select to remove blanc rows from id column?
All rows are like:

```
1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C35991____________________________________________ 
9DC51D0F-C6C9-49AB-B027-CFC067B2CB9E____________________________________________
```

should be:

```
1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C35991
(explanation:there should be no blank space at the end of 991)
9DC51D0F-C6C9-49AB-B027-CFC067B2CB9E                                                                                                                                            


SELECT  
    to_char(trunc("completed"),'yyyy-mm-dd') as "Data",
    count(*) as "Liczba zamkniętych rachunków" 
  FROM Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUEITEM_PERIOD
  LEFT JOIN Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUE_PERIOD on Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUEITEM_PERIOD."queueid"=Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUE_PERIOD."id"
  WHERE Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUE_PERIOD."id"=:queueid AND trunc("completed") between '19/03/01' AND (sysdate-1)
  GROUP BY trunc("completed") order by to_char(trunc("completed"),'yyyy-mm-dd') desc
```

Update:
All rows have same lenght and are different like:

- F121DBB3-96AC-4974-8D88-D39BAFF0CE33
- 1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C35991

I added RTRIM function in where clause, but I have get error:
Could You please modify whole script, please.

````
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.```


SELECT
    to_char(trunc("completed"),'yyyy-mm-dd') as "Data",
    count(*) as "Liczba" 
  FROM Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUEITEM_PERIOD
  LEFT JOIN Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUE_PERIOD on Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUEITEM_PERIOD."queueid"=Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUE_PERIOD."id"
  WHERE RTRIM("Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUE_PERIOD."id"=:queueid",'                                                                        ') short_name AND trunc("completed") between '19/03/01' AND (sysdate-1)
  GROUP BY trunc("completed") order by to_char(trunc("completed"),'yyyy-mm-dd') desc```
````

when I used only below select to trim id works perfectly, but please tell me how to add to whole code

```
  SELECT
  "id",
  RTRIM("id",'                                                                        ') short_name

FROM
  Produkcja2.MV_BPAWORKQUEUE_PERIOD
```

Comment: thanks in advance:)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  "remove . . . rows . . . from column".  A column doesn't contain rows.

Comment: Besides, I couldn't percieve the relevence between that ID column and the shared query  ... Btw  `"Liczba zamkniętych rachunków"`  is not accepted as the  alias for a column as being too long identifier.

Comment: `rtrim("id")` already removes the trailing spaces, no need the second argument for this function.

Comment: ok could You please tell how rtrim in this context should be written, before : or after?

Comment: sample data please :) btw you need to use `@<people_name>` if you want to talk to a spesific person. Here I don't need a @ sign because this part is owned by you. The same logic works also for the comments below answers e.g. no need to prefix the answerer's nick by @ below h(is/er) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one more condition in where clause with `RTRIM` function as following

```
RTRIM(ID) = ID
```

It will restrict the rows with space at the end of original string to satisfy where condition.

If you want them in result to be displayed then use only `RTRIM(ID)` in select clause.

`RTRIM` basically removes all the spaces from right side of the provided string.

Cheers!!

Comment: I added RTRIM function but there is a lot of spaced to remove, and I get error code: *Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there's no leading space within the values of ID column, and the format is fixed as mentioned, I suppose focusing on the part after last dash composed of fixed number for digits and letters, and ending with `991`. So use the below combination of substr and instr functions to extract as expected `ID`:

```
with tab(ID) as
(
  select '1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C35991' from dual union all
  select '1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C35991  987CA' from dual union all
  select '1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C3599154987CA' from dual  
)
select substr(ID,1,regexp_instr(ID,'-\D{2}\d{2}\D\d\D\d{5}')+
                   length(regexp_substr(ID,'\D{2}\d{2}\D\d\D\d{2}991'))) as ID
  from tab;
```

**Edit :** If needed part of the ID values have fixed length equal to the sample (`1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C35991`) shared at the beginnig, then it's simpler to extract by using `length()` function :

```
select substr(ID,1,length('1D0711BC-A37E-4CDD-A0D1-FF26B9C35991')) as ID
  from tab;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5b3f4ff98b7db1195c833b2d29b0b6b5)</kbd>

Comment: thank you, but how can I use it when all rows are different?

Comment: you can express what you mean by example data @KonradKey

Comment: Data means Date, I used it as alias. Liczba means number